# Why my Interstitial Ads show on back button press? Android

Tags: android, admob

When I click the back button, or back from the last activity, then the Interstitial Ads show. But I want to show the ads when the user goes from activity 1 to activity 2. When I change the code a little, Interstitial Ads show but it prevents to sent user to activity 2.

code that shows Interstitial ads on back button press after going activity 2 from activity 1.

```
public void ok(View view) {



        if (InterstitialAd.isLoaded())
            InterstitialAd.show();

         Intent intent = new Intent   (  WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);

        intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, WallpaperService.class));
        startActivity(intent);


    }
```

code that shows Interstitial ads but prevents user to go activity 2

```
 public void ok(View view) {


         Intent intent = new Intent   (  WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);

        intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, WallpaperService.class));
        startActivity(intent);
        if (InterstitialAd.isLoaded())
            InterstitialAd.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're supposed to use something like this:

```
if (mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
                mInterstitialAd.show();
                mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onAdClosed() {
                        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                                .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                                .build();
                        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

                        startActivity(intent);
                        Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
                    }
                });
            } else {
                startActivity(intent);
            }
```

This means when you close the ad, it will direct you to your intended activity. And if there is no ad loading, then it will bring you to next activity immediately.

In your case try:

```
public void ok(View view) {

    if (InterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
        InterstitialAd.show();

        Intent intent = new Intent   (  WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);

        intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, WallpaperService.class));

        InterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

                @Override
                public void onAdClosed() {
                    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                            .addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)
                            .build();
                    InterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);

                    startActivity(intent);
                    Log.i("Ads", "onAdClosed");
                }
       });
   } else {
       startActivity(intent);
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes @Samartian You understand. How can I put your code into my code? It gives some error. my code is below.  public void ok(View view) {
        if (InterstitialAd.isLoaded())
            InterstitialAd.show();



        Intent intent = new Intent(WallpaperManager.ACTION_CHANGE_LIVE_WALLPAPER);

        intent.putExtra(WallpaperManager.EXTRA_LIVE_WALLPAPER_COMPONENT, new ComponentName(this, WallpaperService.class));
        startActivity(intent);


    }

Comment: I have added the code that is correlating with your code. Hope it helps.